# How do I use PayPal Subscriptions to charge a different amount after set interval of time?

Tags: paypal-subscriptions

I need to create a subscription plan where for the first payment user will be charged `$40 / month` for first **4 months**. then after a year the user will be charged `$9 / year`.

How can I create **2 different schemas** for these different intervals of time?
Below is how i am trying to create the plan.

```
{
                                          "product_id": "PROD-6A197088517983824",
                                          "name": "Yearly Plan",
                                          "description": "Yearly plan",
                                          "billing_cycles": [
                                            {
                                              "frequency": {
                                                "interval_unit": "MONTH",
                                                "interval_count": 12
                                              },
                                              "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
                                              "sequence": 1,
                                              "total_cycles": 1
                                            },
                                            {
                                              "frequency": {
                                                "interval_unit": "YEAR",
                                                "interval_count": 1
                                              },
                                              "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
                                              "sequence": 2,
                                              "total_cycles": 0,
                                              "pricing_scheme": {
                                                "fixed_price": {
                                                  "value": "99",
                                                  "currency_code": "USD"
                                                }
                                              }
                                            }
                                          ],
                                          "payment_preferences": {
                                            "auto_bill_outstanding": true,
                                            "setup_fee": {
                                              "value": "10",
                                              "currency_code": "USD"
                                            },
                                            "setup_fee_failure_action": "CONTINUE",
                                            "payment_failure_threshold": 3
                                          }
                                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite straightforward in the [PayPal Subscriptions documentation.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#3-create-a-plan)

For your case:

`"sequence": 1` will be for the $40/month with `"total_cycles": 4`

`"sequence": 2` will be for the $9/year.

Comment: Thanks What will be the type for both of the frequency?

Comment: `"tenure_type": "regular"`, if that is what you are asking

Comment: `{
              "frequency": {
             "interval_unit": "YEAR",
             "interval_count": 1
              },
              "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
              "sequence": 2,
              "total_cycles": 0,
              "pricing_scheme": {
             "fixed_price": {
               "value": "99",
               "currency_code": "USD"
             }
              }
            }`

Comment: Hello, This is the frequency I've used. 

I need sequence 1 should be for 4 months and sequence 2 starts after a year and charge yearly.

Comment: HEy,  I tried but this given an error of 

`details] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [field] => /billing_cycles
                    [location] => body
                    [issue] => MULTIPLE_REGULAR_BILLING_CYCLE_NOT_SUPPORTED
                    [description] => Only one regular billing cycle is allowed.
                )

            [
        )`

Comment: I have added the json above.

Comment: Well then according to that error you'll have to set the first one's type to trial.

Comment: It's seems impossible, it is giving internal server error. When I pass amount to the trial.

Comment: Well you should post the error. But your new JSON in the question does not make sense, it should be interval_count: 1 and total_cycles:4 for the trial.

Comment: Can I create a plan for 
first 4 months => 40 $ 
after a year => 9$ / year

If yes then what will be the json format then? Thanks in advance\